# How do I stop multiple services from taking one intents instructions?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

We have 2 applications that both have identical services to pull messages from a webservice. To save battery power we only need 1 service to do the pulling for both applications, but in case of a uninstall of application1 we need application2's service to take over the pulling.

We are acheiving this by sending an implicit intent to see if any of OUR other apps can start up and take over.

However: If i try just to stop the service, without uninstalling the whole application, it seems that both our applications respond with starting their services (suddenly we go from 1 service to 0 to 2).

**Edited by request since the question was cryptic, some of the answers/comments below will be to the previous question, sorry for the fuss folks!

Comment: Are you sure about your definition of a service? it definitely sounds like a chooser.

Comment: As a secondary comment please read the android developer site and look up Chooser / Service / Activity just to understand what they all mean. They are all specific in their application, help us help you.

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty sure I'm right on this though... We have an app, that has underlying services that onDestroy check if any of our other apps installed need a service to keep running - if so switch to app2 or 3 and run on their service... But I'll take a minute  to read and come back to you! Thanks for the help so far!

-Bobby

Comment: @Bobby: Is 'the service' part of your own app or are you using 3rd party services (not written by you)? If it's your service then don't call it with an implicit intent but instead use bindService() with an explicit intent (specifying the service class).

Comment: It's definitely not a chooser I'm talking about. The chooser is for when you have multiple "activities" that can do just as well as the other activities for an intents task, and the user can choose which one. In our case our intent starts services, and the user does not chose anything.

Comment: @MisterSquonk: Let me explain in further detail so it's clear, as I've been pretty cryptic so far, and I apologize.

Comment: We have 2 applications that both have identical services to pull messages from a webservice. To save battery power we only need 1 service to do the pulling for both applications, but in case of a uninstall of application1 we need application2's service to take over the pulling.

We are acheiving this by sending an implicit intent to see if any of OUR other apps can start up and take over.

However: If i try just to stop the service, without uninstalling the whole application, it seems that both our applications respond with starting their services

Comment: (suddenly we go from 1 service to 0 to 2).

Comment: @Bobby: I'd create a third app which does nothing but contain an IntentService (i.e., it has no Activities, therefore no UI). I'd then remove the service code from both of the other apps and just have them use the single instance of the IntentService which lies dormant when it has nothing to do.

Comment: This was actually a very good answer, and I'll talk it over with the rest of the guys and check our options, I'd still like to know if anyone knows if the Intent Filter has any options for treating multiple service problems, but this would work! Thanks MisterSquonk! :D

Comment: @Bobby: I've upgraded/expanded my comment as an answer. I would definitely recommend IntentService as a possibility. I've found it very versatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways of checking to see if certain apps are installed and (I believe) ways to discover what things are currently running. I'm not aware, however, of any way to provide conditional information in an Intent to say things like 'use this service instance if available' (for example).

My approach would be to create a third app which does nothing but contain an IntentService (i.e., it has no Activities, therefore no UI). I'd then remove the service code from both of the other apps and just have them use the single instance of the IntentService which lies dormant when it has nothing to do.

As the service is specific to your own apps, I'd probably avoid using an implicit Intent (i.e., specifying action/category) and instead use an Intent which explicitly specifies the service class itself. IntentService can be created/started with either startService() or bindService() either or both may be applicable depending on your applications' requirements.

Comment: Cheers for listing it again as an answer so it's "solved"! I owe you MisterSquonk!

Comment: @BobbyTee: Thanks for accepting it. I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a popup asking which app should consume the intent. And the intent is then routed to that app. You can also mark one app as default there.

Perhaps you need to 'reset' this chooser?

Comment: I think I didn't explain the whole problem, which is this;
After a service is destroyed, onDestroy, we ask with a single intent: "Is there any other service that needs to run?" then what we WANT is one of the services that are available to take the reigns and run for our applications that need it.

What happens though, is that all the services start, even though they are all doing the exact same thing, so my question is can we limit the amount of service responses to an intent?

Comment: Please edit your question to better specify the problem then.

Comment: Oh and since these are services, and not activities, no pop-up is available. They just start amongst themselves... O_o

Please specify if you need more info, or if I should phrase my question better, I'm very new to this!

Comment: Yeah with services, my answer is moot. Your original version of the question was talking about apps.